# Count key presses and display them in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, counter, keypress, onkeypress

I made a simple "spacebar simulator" game with HTML and JavaScript. Every time the user presses spacebar an image is replaced with another one, and when the key is released it is reset to the original image.

I would like to add a counter to the page, which counts the number of times the user has pressed spacebar.  The source code is below:

```js
var myRealUrl = "./assets/spacebar.png";
$("body").on("keydown", function (e) {
  if(e.which == 32){   
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", "./assets/spacebar_pressed.png")
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function (e) {
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", myRealUrl)
});

var button = document.getElementById('counter'),
  count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  button.innerHTML = "Click me: " + count;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Spacebar Simulator 2018</h1>
            <span id="counter"><p></p></span>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/spacebar.png" id="spacebar">
        <p>Pressed</p><p id="counter">0</p><p> times.</p>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/spacebar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

So set up a page level variable and increment it in the `keydown` event handler.

Your attempt at the "button" click code didn't work because the `p` element that needed to be clicked had no content inside of it, so it wasn't rendering on the screen and therefore there was nothing to click on.

Also, you can't have more than one element with the same `id` and it's invalid to put a `p` inside of a `span`.

```js
var counter = 0;  // Variable to hold the count
var myRealUrl = "./assets/spacebar.png";
var count = document.getElementById('counter');
$("body").on("keydown", function (e) {
  if(e.which == 32){   
    counter++; // Increment the counter
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", "./assets/spacebar_pressed.png");
    count.textContent = counter; // Log the count
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function (e) {
    $("#spacebar").attr("src", myRealUrl)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Spacebar Simulator 2018</h1>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/spacebar.png" id="spacebar">
  <p>Pressed <span id="counter">0</span> times.</p>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/spacebar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```